# Unable to create array for checkboxes with jquery AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am close but missing something. Im trying to pass variables of multiple checkboxes to a php page with jquery. My code:

```
<div id="students">
    <div class="field">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pupil[a]" value="a" id="pupil"/>
            Pupil A
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pupil[b]" value="b" id="pupil"/>
            Pupil B
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pupil[c]" value="c" id="pupil"/>
            Pupil C
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="occupation">
    <div class="field">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="occupation[Software]" value="Software" id="occupation"/>
            Software
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="occupation[Marketing]" value="Marketing" id="occupation"/>
            Marketing
        </label>
    </div> 
    <div class="field">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="occupation[Teacher]" value="Teacher" id="occupation"/>
            Teacher
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
        var val = [];
        var myval = []; //defining to pass with AJAX
        var theval =[]; //defining to pass with AJAX

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){

          myval[i] = $(this).attr('id');
          theval[i] = $(this).attr('name');
          var newval = myval[i] +"="+ myval[i];


          $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'draftdata.php',
        data : { newval},      //tried this and 
        data : {myval : theval},  // and tried this too
        success: function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
        }
        });

});

});

});
```

I only want to pass the data that was checked in the checkboxes to php. There may be multiple group of checkboxes so the `$_POST['desiredValue']` cannot be defined. So I can only check if its set by `if(isset($_POST['desiredValue']))`.

When I check Software, Marketing and Teacher and on draftdata.php do a `print_r($_POST[])`,I get:

```
Array
(
    [myval] => Array
        (
            [0] => Software
            [1] => Marketing
            [2] => Teacher
        )

)
```

What i want to get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'occupation' = 'Software'
    [1] => 'occupation' = 'Marketing'
    [2] => 'occupation' = 'Teacher'
)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with the same `id`?

Comment: I want to pass the var id to the php `$(this).attr('id')` and pass the value of that checkbox as the value of that id `(theval)`. It just the `data{}` in the AJAX call is causing error i think.

Comment: In HTML you can't have more than one element in a document with the same id.

Comment: Why is your ajax inside your `.each()` function?

Comment: @gcampbell : I can get the result without AJAX, so the `id` is not an issue i think.

@StephanSutter : Moved it outside. No difference. Its still giving same results. `myvar` is passed as "myvar" and not the actual value of the variable to php.

Comment: you don't want it like this? `Array
(
    [occupation] => Array
        (
            [0] => Software
            [1] => Marketing
            [2] => Teacher
        )

)`

Comment: I dont think i will be able to extract the values of occupation from php if i get that value. I want the array occupation[] to be passed to php, but its passing "myval".

Comment: @StephanSutter I was able to get the values in php. My only problem is that only one of the 2 is passed at a time when something from both is checked. Say 1 chkbox from pupil and 2 from occupation are clicked everything is passed in a single array for pupil. I want them to pass in their respective array.

Comment: what did you use in data? `data : { newval},` or `data : {myval : theval},` ?

Comment: tried both. It only passes all the checkboxes in array pupil, if anything from the 1st array is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your html code in this way,

```
    <form id="myform" class="" action="draftdata.php" method="post">
        <div id="students">
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pupil[]" value="a" id="pupil" /> Pupil A
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pupil[]" value="b" id="pupil" /> Pupil B
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pupil[]" value="c" id="pupil" /> Pupil C
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="occupation">
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="occupation[]" value="Software" id="occupation" /> Software
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="occupation[]" value="Marketing" id="occupation" /> Marketing
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="occupation[]" value="Teacher" id="occupation" /> Teacher
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="fsubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

by adding a form and

```
<button type="button" name="button" id="fsubmit">Submit</button>
```

and then using the id of the button `#fsubmit` into our jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fsubmit").click(function(e) {
        var val   = [];
        var id    = []; //defining to pass with AJAX
        var name  = []; //defining to pass with AJAX
        var val = [];

        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i, v){
          id[i]   = $(this).attr('id');
          name[i] = $(this).attr('name');
          val[i]  = $(this).val();
        });

            var url = $('#myform').attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data : {
                    'id': id,
                    'name': name,
                    'val': val
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // $("#result").html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
  });
});
</script>
```

notice that I change some of the variable, change this according to your needs,

```
var val   = [];
var id    = []; //defining to pass with AJAX
var name  = []; //defining to pass with AJAX
var val = [];
```

and also added with this

```
var url = $('#myform').attr('action');
```

and, `dataType: 'json'`,

what the jquery do, when the user click on the button, get the link from the form action and look for the checked values and sent it to the php.

here the sample of the php

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['id']) ) {
  $temp['id'] = $_POST['id'];
}
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) {
  $temp['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
if ( isset($_POST['val']) ) {
  $temp['val'] = $_POST['val'];
}
$data['data'] = $temp;
echo json_encode($data);
```

check your log for the result,

hope this help

Comment: It still doesn't work. Getting the same result. You changed the `name` but the name is not been passed with AJAX to php.

Comment: Do you need both id, names and value?

Comment: i need the name of the id and the value. Sorry if i sound stupid. What i want in php is to have an array of the selected checkboxes. So if Software and Marketing is checked, i want these 2 values in the occupation array to pass to php. thanks.

Comment: I just updated the answer into more details, hope that will help

Comment: thanks @Fil but i cannot define the id when passing to php.

I only want to pass the data that was checked in the checkboxes to php. There may be multiple group of checkboxes so the $_POST['desiredValue'] cannot be defined. So I can only check if its set by if(isset($_POST['desiredValue'])) from php. 

How can i just pass the var from AJAX?

thanks buddy.